Automatic car has stopped using the lower gears to get moving
The problem car is a 2004 holden astra (Australia). Recently, the car has been struggling to get moving due to a lack of engagement with 1st gear. I can usually manually move the gear stick to 1st, then move up through the gears to "Drive" without any issue. Once moving, the car drives without problems. It's only when I come to a complete stop that I have to move the gears manually to get the car moving again.
Sometimes, the gear stick will not engage with 1st gear, and I have to get the car moving in second gear.
Roughly 3 years ago, the car's computer was replaced.
I plan to get it looked at professionally, but was wondering if there is anything I can try myself first - before spending money on this old car?
Thanks in advance.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While no expert, this sounds like you're having an issue with the valve body. When you manually force it to go to the proper gears, it will do that and drive "normally" (yah, it'll use the gears anyways). This seems to point to the valve body to me, but I don't know for sure.

Check your radiator and coolant tank for oily residue. Also check your transmission dipstick (if you have one) for milky residue. This model is known for developing a leak between the trans fluid cooler and engine coolant. Contamination can go in either direction, or both directions. If you have coolant in the trans and it has been there awhile, the trans may be toast.
